# /bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/my_bashrc: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to restore my .bashrc-file to default setting following these instructions:

https://www.ostechnix.com/restore-bashrc-file-default-settings-ubuntu/

As soon as I want to copy the default version of .bashrc into my terminal I get an error:

```
$ cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
-bash: $: command not found
```

`ls -la` shows a couple of files - so it might be an issue of duplicates?
I run into similar problems with `.bash_profile`.

```
-rw-r--r--    1 celestin  staff    10284 28 Nov 16:07 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--@   1 celestin  staff        0 28 Nov 15:30 .bash_profile
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      315 27 Nov 21:12 .bash_profile.save
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      310 27 Nov 22:16 .bash_profile.save.1
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      298 27 Nov 22:17 .bash_profile.save.2
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      293 27 Nov 22:24 .bash_profile.save.3
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      336 27 Nov 22:35 .bash_profile.save.4
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff      285 27 Nov 22:37 .bash_profile.save.5
-rw-r--r--    1 celestin  staff    12288 27 Nov 21:22 .bash_profile.swl
-rw-r--r--    1 celestin  staff    12288 27 Nov 21:21 .bash_profile.swm
-rw-r--r--    1 celestin  staff    12288 27 Nov 21:06 .bash_profile.swn
-rw-r--r--    1 celestin  staff    12288 27 Nov 21:02 .bash_profile.swo
drwx------  351 celestin  staff    11232 28 Nov 16:07 .bash_sessions
-rw-r--r--@   1 celestin  staff        0 28 Nov 15:40 .bashrc.bak
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff       23 27 Nov 22:33 .bashrc.save
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff       19 28 Nov 09:43 .bashrc.save.1
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff       19 28 Nov 09:43 .bashrc.save.2
-rw-------    1 celestin  staff       31 28 Nov 10:05 .bashrc.save.3
drwxr-xr-x    5 celestin  staff      160  6 Jan  2016 .cache
drwxr-xr-x    5 celestin  staff      160 24 Sep  2016 .cisco
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you typing the dollar sign (`$`)? If so, just type `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work either way.

Comment: Well, what is the error message if you type `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`?

Comment: cp: /etc/skel/.bashrc: No such file or directory //

I added my ls -la output above. Maybe that could help?

Comment: So you see, this is quiet a different error message! The message indicates that either the file `/etc/skel/.bashrc` does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the aformentioned file.

Comment: reading my ls -la (see above) it seems to be missing indeed. How do I create one? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: No, I'm not saying your `.bashrc` is missing. I say the `/etc/skel/.bashrc` does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I hear you. So what does that mean? - Or better: What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is offtopic and I'm also not sure what you want to accomplish. You can look up example .bashrc files on the internet.

Comment: Well, I am trying to figure that out myself... I went through every page in the internet but could not find a solution to the problem - I have issues when I am running my python code and I am pretty sure it is related to my .bash_profile and .bashrc  files. So I try to install a default version of them to get everything running again but I get stuck at the above mentioned point.

Comment: I see. Just download from your distribution repository the default .bashrc. Like google for this maybe: `bashrc github ubuntu`.

Comment: Yes, that looks promising! could you tell me how that works? - You would save me a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not copying the $

The response you got back from the bash is that it can't find the "dollar" command